# Getting an error while trying to run a standard google app engine program on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin

Have created a GAE standard Java Project using Eclipse IDE. This is the most basic one and I have not made any changes to it.However when I am trying to debug it, its geting an error.Error message being shown is that port 8080 is already in use.I think I have been able to properly install the GAE plug-in. Could someone please point what the issue is and a solution as well? Sc shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2Xhz.png

Answer (score 0):

This error means that a process is already using the port 8080, so your app can not use it.

You can either use another port or find the process that is using the port and terminate it so the port is free for your app to use. You can follow [these instructions](https://www.isunshare.com/blog/how-to-determine-what-ports-are-being-used-in-windows-10/) for this last approach, which is the one I recommend.

---